Existence of self adjoint idempotents in simple algebras
Let $(A,*)$ be a finite-dimensional simple $K$-algebra with involution. Does $(A,*)$ have a self-adjoint primitive idempotent?
By Wedderburn theorem, $A \cong Mat_n(D)$ for some division $K$-algebra $D$ and integer $n$.
However, if $\star$ is any involution in $ Mat_n(D)$, then the Wedderburn theorem does not gurantee an isomorphism between $(A,*)$ and $(Mat_n(D), \star)$.
The answer is no in general, with the following counter-example:
$A=\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $$*: \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c &d \end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}d & -b\\-c &a \end{bmatrix}. $$
Here, self-adjoint idempotents are zero matrix and the identity. None of them are primitive.
So, how can we characterize involutions such that
$(A,*)$ has a self-adjoint primitive idempotent?

A first remark: in this context we do not speak of "self-adjoint" elements but rather "symmetric".
Let us write $A=\operatorname{End}_D(V)$ for some division algebra $D$ and some $D$-module of the right $V$. We can choose an involution $\sigma$ on $D$ of the same type as $\ast$ (in particular it restricts to the same automorphism of the center), and then there is a hermitian form $h: V\times V\to D$ over $(D,\sigma)$ such that $\ast$ is the adjoint involution with respect to $h$ (so $h(f(u),v) = h(u, f^\ast(v))$ for $u,v\in V$ and $f\in A$).
Then a symmetric primitive idempotent in $A$ is an orthogonal projection on some $1$-dimensional subspace of $V$. This amounts to finding an element $v\in V$ such that $h(v,v)\neq 0$, because then the projection onto $vD$ is our idempotent. It turns out this is always possible (hermitian forms can be diagonalized) except when $A$ is split and $\ast$ is a symplectic involution. This corresponds to the case where $D=Z(A)$ is a field, $\sigma$ is the identity of $D$ (and not some order $2$ automorphism) and $h$ is an alternating bilinear form on $V$.
The counter-example you give is the only symplectic involution on the split algebra $M_2(K)$.

1- Do you mean $\sigma|{Z(A)}=*|{Z(A)}$ by "in particular it restricts to the same automorphism of the center"? Here $V$ can be a minimal left ideal of $A$ and $D=End({}_AV)$ and so ${}_AV_D$ is a bimodule. For any primitive idempotent $e$ of $A$, $eAe \cong D^{op}$ as rings. Now, how can we choose involution $\sigma$ in $D$ with the mentioned property? // 2- Are you saying any involution is induced by a hermitian form, and a symmetric primitive idempotent exists iff that hermitian form is diagonalizable?

@khashayar 2. I guess here is meant that any hermitian form is diagonalizable.
